# Installed apk doesn't start

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I have to write couple tests on `Xamarin UI Test` framework to check apk on emulator. I tried to install my apk in two ways:

1  adb.exe install `path\com.company.mobiledemo.apk`

2 through `Xamarin UI Test`

```
if (platform == Platform.Android)
{
    AndroidApp app = ConfigureApp.Android
        .ApkFile("path\\com.company.mobiledemo.apk")
        .Debug()
        .EnableLocalScreenshots()
        .DeviceSerial("emulator-5554")
        .StartApp();

    return app;
}
```

In first approach apk installed and working correctly. But when apk installed via code above apk will be install but wont launch, just stopped after splash screen.

[image]

I have no idea why because both use the same apk file.

```
NUnit: 3.13.3
NUnit3TestAdapter: 4.2.1
Xamarin.UITest: 2.2.6
Emulator OS: Android 6.0 Api 23
```

Comment: Have you followed all the stoeps of UITest ? Have you add a project reference from the UITest project to the Xamarin.Android project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/xamarin-forms?tabs=windows

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I didn't add any references. Not sure that's necessary. All I have always done was connecting apk in `Xamarin UI Test` proj via code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. It's a bit confused and maybe there is a more easy fix. Problem as I understood is your apk and Instrumentation backend apk must be signed the same cert.

My steps:

1. I installed apk via adb command : `>adb.exe install ~\..\com.company.mobiledemo.apk`
2. Then changed `AppInitializer.cs` like this :

   ```
   if (platform == Platform.Android)
   {
       string keystore = "~\\..\\..\\some.keystore";
       AndroidAppConfigurator appConfigurator = ConfigureApp.Android
           .KeyStore(
           keystore,
           "storePassword",
           "keyPassword",
           "\"keyAlias\""
           )
           .InstalledApp("com.company.mobiledemo.apk")
           .Debug()
           .EnableLocalScreenshots();

       AndroidApp app = appConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode.Clear);
       return app;
   }
   ```
3. Then tried to launch test and got error :

```
System.Exception : Failed to execute: C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A943C412ED6ED5DEB1675E7FDF91843FD0807\20344\SignedTestServer.apk" -storepass bla-bla -keypass bla-bla -keystore "~..\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Certificate\some.keystore" "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A943C412ED6ED5DEB1675E7FDF91843FD0807\TestServer.apk" ""Key Alias"" - exit code: 1

Please type jarsigner -help for usage
Only one alias can be specified
```

It's ok.

4. Open folder from error message :

> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\

You will see something like this :

[image]

5. Delete all and run tests once again. After launching new test data will appear:

[image]

6. Copy command from error message above, go to `C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin` or directory where located `jarsigner.exe`
7. Execute command after `System.Exception : Failed to execute:`

[image]

8. Find `SignedTestServer.apk` and copy it into folder containes `dummy.apk`

[image]

9. Run tests once again and see that `FinalTestServer.apk` appeared

[image]

**PS** Close folder `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest` before 9.